# Постинг на стену контакта произвольного изображеня.

Tags: php, изображения, vkontakte-api

Нашел скрипт, который, используя API контакта, посылает на стену группы новый пост. С его помощью можно прикреплять к посту изображения, но только те, которые уже есть в альбоме группы.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы посылать на стену произвольное изображение? Вроде "http://example.com/images/news/image48.jpg".

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Сначала [загружаете произвольное изображение, получаете его id](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files), и прикрепляете к посту. [Например](https://vk.com/zemlya_sej4as), регулярные снимки со спутника.

Comment: C альбомами проблема в том, что в них максимум - 500 фотографий.

Comment: proof? В упомянутой группе на сегодня 954 записи, каждая с уникальной фотографией. Полет нормальный.

Если хочется шашечек, можно же [создавать альбомы методом API](https://vk.com/dev/photos.createAlbum).